# Generic of type RawRepresentable is misinterpreted as self it seems

Tags: swift, generics, rawrepresentable

To use `NSCoding` with Swift's Enum type I made an extension on `NSCoder`:

```
extension NSCoder {
    func encodeEnum<Enum: RawRepresentable where Enum.RawValue == String>(value: Enum, forKey key: String) {
        self.encodeObject(value.rawValue, forKey: key)
    }

    func decodeEnumForKey<Enum: RawRepresentable where Enum.RawValue == String>(key: String) -> Enum? {
        guard let returnValue = self.decodeObjectForKey(key) as? String else { return nil }
        return Enum(rawValue: returnValue)
    }
}
```

The `encodeEnum` method works fine for a `String`-backed Enum, but when I try to decode the prior encoded Enum like so:

```
enum MyEnum: String { case Something, Other }
class MyEnumClass: NSObject, NSCoding {
    let myEnum: MyEnum

    init(myEnum: MyEnum) {
        self.myEnum = myEnum
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let tmp = aDecoder.decodeEnumForKey("myKey") as? MyEnum else { return nil }

        self.init(myEnum: tmp)
    }
}
```

I get an error on `aDecoder.decodeEnumForKey("myKey")`:

```
Value of type `NSCoder` has no member `RawValue`
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the generic and the condition that `Enum.RawValue == String`. But I do not understand while it's not working, but works for `encodeEnum()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in

```
guard let tmp = aDecoder.decodeEnumForKey("myKey") as? MyEnum else { return nil }
```

the compiler cannot infer the generic placeholder of

```
func decodeEnumForKey<Enum: ...>(key: String) -> Enum?
```

to be `MyEnum`, you have to cast the result to `MyEnum?` instead:

```
guard let tmp = aDecoder.decodeEnumForKey("myKey") as MyEnum? else { return nil }
```

so that the return type is inferred as `MyEnum?` from the calling context.